# VS Code adding dubious spaces when Go syntax incorrect

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

For example, this code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    foo := "bar""
    fmt.Println(foo)
}
```

turns into

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    foo: = "bar""
    fmt.Println(foo)
}
```

on save. Note the assignment and the double double quotes. This erroneous replacement affects the entire file. I believe it started to happen with the last version or the one before.

Go options enabled:

```
"go.formatTool": "goreturns"
```

Same thing happens with `gofmt`.

VS Code version 1.25.1, go version go1.10 darwin/amd64.

Any ideas why this happens?

Thanks!

Comment: It's doing the best it can with invalid syntax. Typically it refuses to format a file with invalid syntax, but it's hard to say exactly what's going on without seen those lines in context.

Comment: Have you installed go extension for VS code.

Comment: @Adrian changed the code snippet. The code is within $GOPATH. Note that this didn't happen before, started fairly recently.

Comment: @Himanshu Yes, the "Go for Visual Studio Code" plugin is installed.

Comment: I really don't get it why the downvotes without an explanation... If you need more clarification, please do tell.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this issue using `go fmt` or `goreturns`, directly or via VS Code's format on save. In each test it correctly does nothing because the file is invaild.

Comment: @IvanSavcic `foo := "bar""`  this code line is wrong remove the last inverted commas and then save the file. See if it stills change the format to wrong one you are getting

Comment: @Adrian I can't reproduce it from the command line, either. It properly notices the error and doesn't rewrite the file.

Comment: @Himanshu But that's the thing: my error shouldn't modify the entire file. When I "don't see" the double double quotes, save the file, fix the error and save it again, those extra, erroneous spaces remain, rendering the source file invalid.

Comment: If VSCode is saving the file when it should present an error, it seems you should open an issue with VSCode (or the appropriate plugin for handling Go files)

Comment: @JimB Already did. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. Check if you have the extension "Visual Studio Code Format", as it was the cause in my case (now working fine since I disabled it). Version 0.0.6 does not seem to be a joke... The rest of the Go extensions seem to be fine.

Note: the side effects of this extension can be disastrous on a big file, since it will reformat every single assignment.

Comment: You, sir, are a champion! That was the issue, indeed! Thanks a bunch!